# Error including boost libs in VS project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, boost-thread

I'm trying to compile a VS2008 C++ project on a 64bit platform. In this project I use boost threads. I can correctly compile the project on a 32bit platform.

On the 64bit platform I downloaded a pre-compiled boost libreries (for 64bit). I added the path to the compiled libs directory in `C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`. I'm sure the path is the correct.

When i try to compile I get the error:

```
Error   34  fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_49.lib'    BioCpp  BioCpp
```

I'm sure I actually have this file on my computer, and that i correctly set the `C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories` path.

Maybe I'm missing something else...can someone provide some help?

PS: I'm working on a shared server, I cannot build the libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a library, not an include file, so the "Additional Include Directories" setting is irrelevant. Add the path to the "Additional Library Directories" setting under "Linker" in the project configuration.